# Returning randomized variable data javascript

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, return

Basically i have managed to randomized 2 variable's value with this codes:

```
function getRandomPosition()
{
var xx = document.body.clientWidth;
var yy = document.body.clientHeight;
var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random()*yy);
var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random()*xx);
}
```

This is working fine. Next i made a image random using this randomized coordinates.

```
function randomly()
{
var yx = getRandomPosition(img);
img.style.top = yx[0];
img.style.left = yx[1];
return[yx];
}
```

Next i want to constantly monitor the position of the mouse and the position of the image.

```
function plswork()
{
var yxx=getRandomPosition();
if((event.clientX < yxx[1]-210)||event.clientX>yxx[1]+340) //only comparing the x axis~~ etcetc
{ //play an audio track
}
}

document.onmousemove= plswork;//when mouse move, run that function.
```

HOWEVER, the problem i have now is that the image is spawning everywhere once i move the mouse as well. And if i call the getRandomPosition(); function it will run itself again and give me a different set of numbers to check with the mouse. 
Can anyone give me suggestions? or help thanks

My target is to check the mouse position and compare it to the randomized location that the image is spawned in. The 'yx' in function randomly() tells me the coordinates of the location the image is spawned in. So to bring this function over i have to return it, but when i do that in function plswork(), whenever i move my mouse, it will call and execute the entire function spawning images randomly... BUT, if i call the function getRandomPosition() to replace the var yx in function plswork(), im comparing a different set of coordinates from the 'yx' in the function randomly()..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of basic things are missing from your Javascript: the function `getRandomPosition()` declares only local variables and doesn't return any value for other parts of the program to use; the function `getRandomPosition()` is called  with the parameter `img`, but no parameter is taken by `getRandomPosition()`; CSS Styles `top` and `width` are set without "px"; you're calling `getRandomPosition()` again, expecting to get the same values, instead of storing them the first time...

Anyway, here's a quick example of a script that places an image at a random position and then does something (in this case: move the image) when the mouse gets within a certain distance from the image. Have a good look and check the differences with your original script.

I'm using `doStuff.pos` as a way to store a static variable `pos` in the function `doStuff()`; this way, the variable holds its value between repeated calls to the function. (Other people may prefer using a global variable declared outside the function.)

```js
function getRandomPosition() {
    var maxX = document.body.clientWidth - 32;
    var maxY = document.body.clientHeight - 32;
    var rndX = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxX);
    var rndY = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxY);
    return {x: rndX, y: rndY};
}
function randomizeImage() {
    var pos = getRandomPosition();
    var img = document.getElementById("image");
    img.style.left = pos.x + "px";
    img.style.top = pos.y + "px";
    return pos;
}
function doStuff() {
    if (!event) doStuff.pos = randomizeImage();
    else if (event.clientX < doStuff.pos.x + 96 
          && event.clientX > doStuff.pos.x - 64
          && event.clientY < doStuff.pos.y + 96
          && event.clientY > doStuff.pos.y - 64) {
        doStuff.pos = randomizeImage(); // or do other stuff here
    }
}
doStuff(); // call first time without event
document.addEventListener("mousemove", doStuff)
```

```css
BODY {min-height: 218px; margin: 0; border: 1px solid #CCC;}
IMG {position: relative; width: 32px; height: 32px;}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ebdcdc75fd352485e37d13c2d7526372?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" />
```

Or, if you don't mind using global variables:

```js
var posX, posY; // global variables

function getRandomPosition() {
    var maxX = document.body.clientWidth - 32;
    var maxY = document.body.clientHeight - 32;
    posX = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxX);
    posY = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxY);
}
function randomizeImage() {
    getRandomPosition();
    var img = document.getElementById("image");
    img.style.left = posX + "px";
    img.style.top = posY + "px";
}
function doStuff() {
    if (event.clientX < posX + 96 
    &&  event.clientX > posX - 64
    &&  event.clientY < posY + 96
    &&  event.clientY > posY - 64) {
        randomizeImage(); // or do other stuff here
    }
}
randomizeImage(); // initialize position
document.addEventListener("mousemove", doStuff)
```

```css
BODY {min-height: 218px; margin: 0; border: 1px solid #CCC;}
IMG {position: relative; width: 32px; height: 32px;}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ebdcdc75fd352485e37d13c2d7526372?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" />
```

You could also use closures for this, but they're less straightforward to explain and understand. Basically, the function `doStuff()` is defined inside the function `randomizeImage()`, and therefor it has access to the variables declared in `randomizeImage()`. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1) for more information.

```js
function randomizeImage() {
    var img = document.getElementById("image");
    var maxX = document.body.clientWidth - 32;
    var maxY = document.body.clientHeight - 32;
    var posX = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxX);
    var posY = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxY);
    img.style.left = posX + "px";
    img.style.top = posY + "px";

    function doStuff() {
        if (event.clientX < posX + 96 && event.clientX > posX - 64
        &&  event.clientY < posY + 96 && event.clientY > posY - 64) {
            img.classList.add("mousenear");
        } else {
            img.classList.remove("mousenear");
        }
    }
    return doStuff;
}

var myFunc = randomizeImage();                  // randomizeImage() returns doStuff()
document.addEventListener("mousemove", myFunc); // so doStuff() is called
```

```css
BODY {min-height: 218px; margin: 0; border: 1px solid #CCC;}
IMG {position: relative; width: 32px; height: 32px;}
.mousenear {-webkit-transform: rotate(45deg); transform: rotate(45deg);}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/ebdcdc75fd352485e37d13c2d7526372?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1" />
```

Comment: Hello ive integrated it into my codes but im still missing one part of it, How do i keep "pos" updated in doStuff() whenever i call randomizeImage()?

Comment: @Jerru Only call randomizeImage() from doStuff(), because that's where the value is stored, and call it as doStuff.pos = randomizeImage(). In fact, you could declare randomizeImage() inside doStuff(), so it is only visible to doStuff(). If you need to do things differently for some reason, you could always use global variables; see the second code snippet I added.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do here exactly, but I'll try to help. To start, declare your image position `yx` outside of randomly() so you can access it within plswork()

```
function getRandomPosition(){...}

var yx = null;
function randomly()
{
  yx = getRandomPosition();
  img.style.top = yx[0];
  img.style.left = yx[1];
}

function plswork()
{
  if((event.clientX < yx[1]-210)||event.clientX>yx[1]+340)
  { //play an audio track
  }
}
document.onmousemove= plswork;//when mouse move, run that function.
```

Comment: Hello thanks for replying. Firstly my aim is to check if the mouse comes into a certain proximity range of the image. So to constantly check i need to keep calling the function plswork(), and in it, the if statement, variable yx needs to have the same value as it was in the function randomly(). however, if i use 'return' in function randomly to return the value of yx, and call it in function plswork(), it will keep randomly generating images whenever my mouse moves.